# using a long integer in in snprintf will not go over 65k

Tags: printf, long-integer

I am trying to format and display zero padded long integers with the snprintf command

```
long position = 0;   // defined elsewhere in the program

long micronPerStep = 5;  
long adjustedPosition = (position / micronsPerStep) * 25;
char txt[17];

int n = snprintf(txt,16,"%09u       ",adjustedPosition);
```

The adjustedPosition will range from -1 to 99999999.  I have tried d and u, but the number goes negative at about 65,xxx.  What am I doing wrong???

Comment: What version of c compiler are you using? 32-bit, 64=bit, 16-bit maybe? I would say check the documentation of snprintf() format-string of your compiler. What is %u? Maybe try %lu, %d or %ld.

Comment: I am using the arduino environment, so not real sure what version of C++ that would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%u` is the format code for printing `unsigned int`.

If you want to print `unsigned long`, you need `%lu`.

Comment: P.S. I think, technically, the standard only allows you to print `unsigned long`, not `long`, with `%lu`. But I would be surprised if any environment will hold you to that technicality.

Comment: I tried unsigned long, but same result. Instead of %1u, I used %09u because I need it zero padded left to nine digits.

Comment: Sorry, my eyes are not real good, so I missed that you suggested %lu rather tha %1u.  I will try that.